# Check link variable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, contains, window.location

Take for example, a page as follows:

> http://www.example.com/Page.asp?Page=About

With JavaScript, how can I check if the window's location contains `?Page=About`?

This is the code I have so far, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window.location:contains('?Page=About')").length !== 0) 
{
alert("Currently on About page");
}
else {
}
});
```

Please help :)

Thanks

Comment: `')"` is that correct? shouldn't it just be `')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.indexOf()`  instead of `contains`

```
if ( window.location.href.indexOf('?Page=About') > -1)
```

`window.location` contains the Location object .. The href attribute holds the `url`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgBW4/)**

Comment: It's not working for me, could you possibly post a link to a demo?

Comment: aahh.. right .. Check edited code.. The `$(` inside the if loop is a typo

Comment: Thanks! I see it working now, but is there any way to have indexOf check the whole URL. It appears to be only checking the domain which isn't very useful in my case.

Comment: `.href` give you the entire url.. In the fiddle I was just using as an example .. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location